# Specify only Time in DateTime field (ISO-8601) in Hyperledger

Tags: datetime, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, datetime-format, hyperledger-composer

I'm working on [Hyperledger Composer Playground](https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/) and want to specify only time in `DateTime` field skipping the Date completely. But whenever I try to create the asset, everytime I'm getting `RangeError: Invalid time value` error.

I tried giving default value to the variable in model file in some varieties of the following example but doesn't work either.

`o DateTime dispatchTime default = "T06:18:42.716Z"`

I must be missing some obvious thing in this as it is a ISO-8601 standard format but couldn't find exact solution to get it working specifically in Hyperledger Composer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't store only Time in a `DateTime` (thats why its called DateTime) - you could store Time as a String? Otherwise its something like : `new Date(); var mydate = d.toISOString(); ` See also en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_860 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `invalid time` error because you **can not store just time** in your `dispatchTime` variable as it is an [ISO-8601 Date-Time format](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003169814.htm). You can check it

But then also, if you want to store **only** time, you can convert it in one of the transaction processor functions in your `logic.js` file as follows:

> tx.assetObject.dispatchTime = new Date().toISOString().split(/T/)[1];

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

No, you **can't** store only time to `DateTime` variable.

As described in the docs, it will only accept **an ISO-8601 compatible time instance, with optional time zone and UTZ offset**.

You can manually convert it to only time format at the time of response.

For more details of Hyperledger Primitive types, check out the link below:

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/cto_language